# What does the phrase 'get even' in this sentence mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

[Lyrics of the song](http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/3530822107858717911/) *(passage)*:

> There's nothing worse they can do
>
> There's only one thing to do
>
> **Get even**
>
> So cut it up
>
> wrap it up
>
> out of it
>
> out of luck

[I've already asked one question about the word 'even'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123617/can-i-use-the-verb-even-in-such-expression-i-cant-even-their-knowledge)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means take revenge, or to do to others equal (usually harm) because they have harmed you. From [macmillian](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get-be-even-with-someone):

> to punish or to have punished someone by causing them as much trouble
>   or harm as they have caused you

Comment: Thanks a lot. What do you think about this [question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123617/can-i-use-the-verb-even-in-such-expression-i-cant-even-their-knowledge)

Answer (score 2):

**get (or be) even**

phrase of even

1. *informal*

> inflict trouble or harm on someone similar to that which they have inflicted on oneself.

"I'll get even with you for this"

© Google Search